# Импорт в таблицу MySQL из CSV файла

Tags: mysql, csv

Как импортировать данные в таблицу MySQL из CSV файла?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос:

```
LOAD DATA 
LOCAL INFILE '/path/to/file/file.csv' 
INTO TABLE table_name 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```